# admob real ad can't show

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

when i using the test id the AD is show properly, but when i using my own id the AD does not show anymore.
my app is not public on play store yet. So is it related to my app is not public on play store so i can't see the AD, or i do something wrong? i had verify my admob account and created a week.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHElT.png)
and this is my debug log capture when i request the AD.
is it say i must upload on play store for showing the real AD?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ads do not appear immediately after you enter your advertising ID and admob advertising IDs. After a while, google starts showing ads (It may take a few days). If your test ads are showing, I don't think it's a problem.

Comment: but i enter my id about 3 month it is does not show anything. but when i use test id is show correctly